# Any extension/plugin for visual studio 2019 to see inherited methods from interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

what I'm looking for is that I can see all methods/properties that an interfaces/abstract class inherent from other interfaces/abstract class.
Because sometimes the inheritance of some bigger project is confusing.
I already that you can skip to the "base" interface.

Example:

```
public interface IDisposable

{

    void Dispose();

}

public interface IClean : IDisposable
{
    [inherited:IDisposable] void Dispose();
}
```

Of course this example is trivial but for some bigger projects it could be much bigger

Edit: Typos

Comment: There is already an icon for overridden and interface types in the left hand side channel, or that might be resharper, i am not sure. You could potentially write you own though if you had the will

Comment: Resharper does this via [Navigate -> derived symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Inheritor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any extension/plugin for visual studio 2019 to see inherited methods
> from interfaces

**Actually**, just like **Michael** and **llian** said, [Resharper Extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this job.

And you can check the [Resharper document about Derived Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Inheritor.html)

**Besides**, **Resharper** is a paid vs extension but new users have 30 days of free use.

When you finish it, please first click on the interface on the code editor and then click **Extensions**-->**ReSharper**-->**Navigate**-->**Derived Symbols** or just use the shortcut key `Ctrl+Alt+B`.